# Japanese Characters are not being printed in Zebra Printer - ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

This following ZPL code has different Japanese characters and it is only printing English characters and not printing Japanese characters. What's wrong here?

```
^XA^CI28^MMT^PW809^LL0406^LS0^FS^FT420,160^A0N,24,26^FH^FDPick List:%1s^FS^FT217,350^FB600,6,0,J^AJN,18,20E:GOTHIC35.FNT^FH^FD%2s^FS^FT20,230^AJN,24,26^FH^FD住所:^FS^FT420,207^A0N,24,26^FH^FDTest Obj:%3s^FS^FT420,135^A0N,24,26^FH^FDQty:^FS^FT465,135^A0N,24,26^FH^FD%4s^FS^FT20,207^A0N,24,26^FH^FDProject:%5s^FS^FT20,121^FT558,138^FB240,4,0,J^A0N,24,26^FH^FD%6s^FS^FT420,68^A0N,24,26^FH^FDModification:^FS^FT20,87^FT96,93^FB250,2,0,J^A0N,24,26^FH^FD%7s^FS^FT20,68^A0N,24,26^FH^FDName:^FS^FT420,48,^A0N,24,26^FH^FDVersion:%8s^FS^FT20,48^A0N,24,26^FH^FDPart No:%9s"^FS^FT20,135^A0N,24,26^FH^FDBin Loc:%10s^FS^FT20,160^A0N,24,26^FH^FDRequest List:^FS^FT160,160^A0N,24,26^FH^FD%11s^FS^FT20,183^A0N,24,26^FH^FDRequester:%12s^FS^PQ%13s,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Output:

[image]

Try the code and output here online: http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use the standard international characters set (^CI28) and the native Zebra fonts to print Japanese glyphs.
You have to install the Andale font and use the ^CI26 if you want to embedd the Japanese glyphs directly in the code.
On Labelary you will not be able to simulate this because you can't use additional fonts.
Have a look here for a guide
https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/fonts/printers-printing-oriental-glyphs

Comment: We need to use GOTHIC35 font, It's a customer requirement

Comment: Do you need the gothic font just for the English text? If so, you can print that with the font you want and the glyphs with the Andale font